# Holding down <C-x-left/right> to switch between windows

Tags: key-bindings

I have

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-x-right>") 'other-window)
```

in my `.emacs` file.

When I use this keymap, I am able to switch the window one time. When I hit the right arrow key again nothing happens.

How do I have to denote the keymap to that I can use it like this:

1. `C-x` *pressed and held*
2. *press right* to change window
3. *press right again* change window
4. *press right again* change window and so on

Comment: Use `(kbd "C-x <right>")`, not `(kbd "<C-x-right>")`. You can use `C-h k` to see how Emacs denotes a key sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Using the [`hydra`](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) package (also available from Melpa/GNU Elpa) could be one of the solutions.

Below hydra-binding style does not take over the whole `C-x` map.<sup>1</sup> The hydra hints will show up only after you hit `C-x <right>` or `C-x <left>` for the first time.

After evaluating the below code (or adding it to your config and restarting emacs),

- You can now do `C-x <right> <right> <right> <left> <right> <left> <left>` ..
- Whenever you want to get out of that hydra, hit `C-g`.

#### Original

```el
(defhydra hydra-other-window
  (global-map "C-x"
              :color red)
  "other window"
  ("<right>" other-window "→")
  ("<left>" (lambda () (interactive) (other-window -1)) "←"))
```

---

#### Alternative without hints

If you do not want to see any hints, even the "hydra title window" (known as `lv` in the `hydra` package), add the below `hydra-set-property` form<sup>2</sup> in addition to the above hydra definition [[Reference](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/issues/196)].

```el
(hydra-set-property 'hydra-other-window :verbosity 0)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That is the "Don't mess with the prefix" style described [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki/Binding-Styles).

<sup>2</sup> If you get an error saying that `hydra-set-property` is undefined, ensure that you have the latest version of `hydra` installed from Melpa.

*This is possibly one of the simplest hydras possible. Check out [its wiki](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki) for more hydra application examples. :)*

Comment: Is i possible to not show the "hint" at the bottom when switching between window, since the hint is redundant so such a simple task

Comment: @DanielHitzel Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @DanielHitzel I have added a slightly expanded version of his hydra to [my config](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/bdc1194b439b4adcd62aefd1a278bd74ad9441fb/setup-files/setup-windows-buffers.el#L462-L471).

Comment: nice, I opened a issue here: https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/issues/196

Comment: @DanielHitzel I would not suggest publishing `(setq hydra-is-helpful nil)` in the answer above (as you suggested in an edit). Because that can cause a lot of confusion, especially to people who use multiple hydras and borrow that customization. In my experience, this is probably the only hydra for which setting `hydra-is-helpful` to `nil` is fine.

Comment: Yeah, you are right - that is confusing. In the issue there was a perfect proposal. You can simply prevent hints for each hydra def by the following code (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

(Function `repeat-command`, shown here, is also defined in library [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el), but *you do not need any library or package* outside vanilla Emacs for this simple question.  This answer makes use of standard Emacs library `repeat.el`, but nothing else.)

You can use function **`repeat-command`** to "repeatify" any nonrepeatable command.  Here it is used to repeatify `other-window'.

```el
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
  (let ((repeat-message-function  'ignore))
    (setq last-repeatable-command  command)
    (repeat nil)))

(defun next-window-repeat (count)
  "Select the next window.
With a prefix arg N, select the Nth next window.
A negative prefix arg reverses the direction."
  (interactive "p")
  (require 'repeat)
  (repeat-command `(lambda () (interactive) (other-window ',count))))

(defun previous-window-repeat (count)
  "Select the previous window.
With a prefix arg N, select the Nth previous window.
A negative prefix arg reverses the direction."
  (interactive "p")
  (require 'repeat)
  (repeat-command `(lambda () (interactive) (other-window ',(- count)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <C-right>") 'next-window-repeat)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x <C-left>")  'previous-window-repeat)
```

The problem with what you did is that you bind `C-x <right>` to `other-window`, and `other-window` does not read any key after it has switched you to the other window - it is done. So you have to hit `C-x <right>` again, to invoke `other-window` again.

In command `other-window-repeat`, `repeat-command` invokes `other-window`, and then if the last key is hit again, it invokes `other-window` again...

Comment: I notice that with this solution I cannot perform something like right, right, left, while Hydra allows this behavior.

Comment: Correct. With this code you need to interject `C-x` to change direction: `C-x right right C-x left C-x right...`

Comment: Using exactly this code I got `void function repeat-command` (both in emacs 24.5.1 and 25.0.50.5).

Comment: @JeanPierre: Oops; sorry. I accidentally deleted the definition of `repeat-command` the last time I edited it. Should be OK now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach -- Use any key (e.g., `C-x o`) for a command that reads the up/down arrow keys to move among the windows.  For this you will need library [Do Re Mi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) ([`doremi.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi.el)).  (This code is also in [`doremi-cmd.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi-cmd.el).)

```el
(defun doremi-windows+ ()
  "Use up and down arrow keys to cycle among windows of selected frame.
You can use `C-g' to quit and return to the originally selected window."
  (interactive)
  (unless (require 'doremi) (error "You need library `doremi.el' for this command")) 
  (let ((sel-win  (selected-window)))
    (condition-case nil
        (doremi-windows-1)
      (quit (select-window sel-win)))))

(defun doremi-windows-1 ()
  "Helper-function for `doremi-windows+'."
  (doremi (lambda (newval) (select-window newval 'norecord) newval)
          (selected-window)
          nil
          nil
          (reverse (window-list))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'doremi-windows+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach -- Similar to the behavior of the answer that uses library [Do Re Mi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) ([`doremi.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi.el)), but using library [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) instead.

[Multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) `icicle-select-window` lets you move among windows by cycling using the up/down arrow keys, but by default you need to hold `Control` pressed while doing that.  (And you need to hit `RET` to end the command to choose the last window selected.)

The reason is this: *You can also select windows by name*, using completion. Each window is given the name of its buffer (windows showing the same buffer are uniquified with a numerical suffix).  And besides completing a name you can cycle among the names (completion candidates) using the arrow keys (without `Control`). So: arrow keys to cycle among names; `Control` + arrow keys to cycle among them and select the windows at the same time.

So you can bind, say, `C-x o` in `icicle-mode-map` to command `icicle-select-window`, then use `C-x o C-<down> C-<down> C-<down>...` to successively select windows.

I said "by default" for the use of `Control` because you can use `M-g` in the minibuffer to flip its use, so that instead of needing to use `Control` + arrow key to act on a completion candidate you can use just the arrow key, and instead of using just the arrow key to cycle among window names you use `Control` + arrow key.

In that case, you would use just `C-x o <down> <down> <down>...` (the same as for Do Re Mi).

You can roll this alternative behavior into its own command this way:

```el
(defun my-icy-select-window ()
  "Same as `icicle-select-window' but act without holding `Control'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig  icicle-use-C-for-actions-flag))
    (when orig (icicle-toggle-C-for-actions))   ; Same as `M-g`
    (icicle-select-window)
    (when orig (icicle-toggle-C-for-actions)))) ; Same as `M-g`
```

To bind `C-x o` (or any other key) to, say, `my-icy-select-window` you customize user option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings` to add an entry for it. (Do not try to use `define-key` with `icicle-mode-map`.)